# how many copies of Hitchhiking with an Angel

Tags: non-fiction

My brother wrote and it was published in 2003. Not a novel but it was published and can find even in amazon.He has never recieved 1 penny. he asked me many times to find out what I could His name as author is Walter Scott III. His real name is Walter Scott Blamer III.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE, Alison! I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What are you trying to find out? What's the problem you're facing? Could you perhaps [edit] your question to make it a bit clearer?

Comment: `sales = quality * marketing`. Zero marketing gets you zero sales, no matter how good your book is. People can't buy an ebook when they don't know it exists.

Answer (score 6):

The sales rank for that title is #12,763,677. This number is available on the book's amazon page.

You can input that number in a calculator like [this one](https://www.tckpublishing.com/amazon-book-sales-calculator/) and see that with such a low rank, the book is selling zero copies per month. There may be other calculators.

More broadly, a self published book will sell very few copies without some form of marketing. Books do not sell themselves--and this is one advantage of trade publishing over self publishing. Trade publishers usually market the book a bit. Self publishing has other advantages--like the ability to publish one's book without a middle-man.

Comment: `without some form of marketing` like talking about it on a popular website?

Comment: @bruglesco LOLs I don't think she is going to sell one of those books here. But there are ways to use SM to market books.